# ADODB connection parameter issue

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am getting error as

> Too few parameters expected 1

on below line. Please assist

```
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, 3, 1
```

Complete coding

```
Dim Conn As New adodb.Connection
Dim mrs As New adodb.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
Conn.Open sconnect
sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [DataSheet$A1:D5325] where [Vertical Name]= '" & Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List(i) & "'"
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, 3, 1
Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(lastrow, 4).Value = mrs.RecordCount
mrs.Close
Conn.Close
```

Comment: `HDR=Yes'` think this needs to be `Extended Properties="HDR=Yes"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error message is not very intuitive :(

That is because when the field names in your SQL query do not match the table fields name:

> Too few parameters expected 1

means that `1` filedname that you are using in your SQL-Statement is not available in your table.

So probably a field called `Vertical Name` does not exist!

---

I also highly recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly to avoid mistyping in variable names: Eg. `sSQLSting` was obviously meant to be `sSQLString`. If you don't use `Option Explicit` you will run into issues soon.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, I have mocked up some dummy data, and the following works

```
Sub Data_Extract()

Dim c As New ADODB.Connection
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim s As String

s = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Workspace\Dummy Data\SAMPLE_GENERAL.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

c.Open s

r.Open "Select * from [Sheet1$A1:E5] where [field 1]='b'", c, 3

End Sub
```

[image]